# Access instance from callback function

Tags: c++, callback, glfw

How can I access the class instance inside a GLFW3 input callback function, for example [this one](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga592dd1919f8a1dc7576b13cdd8b7b695).

I want my instance do something when a specific event happens. Each instance might do something different for a specific event.

Specifically, my class has a std::map< int, std::function< void()>>, where a key is mapped to a function.

EDIT: I tried the following, but this gives me an error that it doesn't match the glfwSetKeyCallback function call.

```
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, [this](GLFWwindow * window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods){
    addCommand(m_events.at(key));
});
```

Comment: You mean when a key is mapped to a function, right?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Um, sure? I mean, a key is pressed and the corresponding function will be called.

Comment: I only asked because "where a function is mapped to a key." seemed the exact opposite of the proposed map immediately before. Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: I always thought it was the other way around. Well, you always learn something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58541/how-can-i-associate-a-key-callback-with-a-wrapper-class-instance).

You need something like this:

```
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, this);
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, [](GLFWwindow * window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods){

    Window * win = static_cast<Window *>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));
    win->addCommand(win->m_events.at(key));

});
```